# SystemVerilog random data generated only for valid signal

Tags: random, constraints, system-verilog

I am new to SV and would like to get some opinions about randomization. I have two signals.

```
rand bit [20:0] data;
rand bit data_valid;
```

I want to generate random data only when data_valid signal goes high. When valid signal is low, data should contain the previous signal. I have tried the following on

```
constraint valid_data {data -> data_valid ==1'b1; }
```

It generates random data when valid signal is high but then data becomes 0 when valid signal goes low. Is there any other way to do that? What I want is data signal should not change when valid becomes low. It should keep the current value of valid signal goes low.

Another issue is the randomization of `data_valid` signal. This is a 1 bit signal and I want to make this signal high randomly for 1 clock cycle only. At the moment it can remain high for any clock cycles which I don't want.

Comment: I'm guessing you've got `data` and `data_valid` defined in a class. These aren't signals, they're class fields. Also, there's no concept of clock cycles when randomizing these fields. Any temporal behavior has to be modeled by you.

Comment: You seem to be mixing concepts here (signals going high, randomizing, clock cycles, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

You need to build a state machine by saving a copy of the previously generated values

```
class tx;
  rand bit [20:0] data;
  rand bit data_valid;
  bit [20:0] prev_data;
  bit prev_data_valid;
  function void post_randomize;
    prev_data = data;
    prev_data_valid = data_valid;
  endfunction
  constraint one_cycle { prev_data_valid -> data_valid == 0;}
  constraint latch_data { !prev_data_valid -> data == prev_data;}
endclass
```

This works assuming you call randomize() once per clock cycle.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I was able to solve my first problem. But still can not figure out how to generate random valid signal which will stay high one clock cycle only. Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you include your solution, it will be helpful to others who encounter a similar problem, and Welcome to Stackoverflow.